# Clang++ vs g++ difference in overloaded function declaration order

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

I found a difference in clang++ vs g++ behavior when adding an overloaded function definition for something in the `<cmath>` library.

Specifically, in this program:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

double cos(double x) throw();

int main() {
  std::cout << cos(1.0) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

double cos(double x) throw() {
  return 10;
}
```

when I compile with `clang++`, it calls my overloaded version of `cos` and prints `10`, but with `g++` it calls the version in the math library and prints `0.540302`.

Interestingly, `g++` will also call my overloaded `cos` if I put the function definition (not just the prototype) before `main`.

Is there some unspecified behavior here, or a bug in one of these compilers? I can't figure out what the standard says should happen in this case.

I have tried this with multiple versions of both compilers and get the same behavior, with no warnings except that parameter `x` is unused.

Comment: You are not overloading anything. You are redefining an existing library function. The effect of this is undefined.